# AutoIT Script Create and Run

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line, autoit

As i am creating Auto-IT .au3 File in WPF application and want to execute (compile) once it is created.

I have tried with Process.start(ScriptFile.au3) , but what it actually doing is just open the file in Auto-IT Script Editor but i want go one step further to run itself.

As i don't want to create a script.exe and execute using Process.Start(Script.exe) because i m creating script at run time.

Is it possible to send Parameters for Script.au3 (not script.exe please) by using Command line arguments?

Suggestions are also fine if there are any alternate way :)

Answer (score 0):

To run a script from the command line, you need to run the AutoIt interpreter, with the script as an argument. The full syntax is:

```
AutoIt3.exe /AutoIt3ExecuteScript ScriptFile.au3 parameters
```

It is also possible to run the script without needing to know the path to the interpreter, either by using ShellExectute with the Run verb, or reading the location of the interpreter from the registry directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
string otherParametersVar = @"Your Script's Parameters Here";
processo = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
processo.StartInfo.FileName = "AutoIt3.exe";
processo.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/AutoIt3ExecuteScript ScriptFile.au3 " + otherParametersVar;
processo.Start();
```